# local variables in document.ready() and other defined functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

In jQuery you can have multiple calls for the various page and other events, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

And you can add multiple 'ready' function definitions along the way, you're not limited to only one.  Of course this helps by keeping code defined close to where it's being used.

My question is, if in one of the `document.ready` function declarations I declare a local variable using `var`, will it be available in another `document.ready` function declaration that's also used by the page?

I'm not sure how jQuery works in circumstances like these; whether it weaves the various functions' scopes together somehow or if each of those functions runs in standalone fashion when the ready event is fired, each having no idea about the others' variables.  (I'd guess the second.)

Comment: jQuery has/can have no effect on scope. If the `var` is in a function, it's not accessible outside *that* function

Comment: *" (I'd guess the second.)"* Test, don't guess.

Comment: @user1689607-- Part of the reason for my question was to facilitate a discussion on why it works the way it does; I realize I can rotely test it in jsfiddle to see if A or B happens.

Comment: @user1689607: Indeed, but an empirical test could only say *what*, not *why*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Absolutely, but it's a very important step. Then the question would be a much more pleasing form: *"Here's what I've done... Here's what I've observed... Here's what I expected... Please help me understand."* Instead of the all too common: *"If I do this, what will happen?"*

Comment: @larryq: FYI, the function you pass to `.ready()` is just dropped into an Array that is local to the jQuery internal code. They're invoked one at a time when ready. Though I think now their deferred system is used to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is, if in one of the `document.ready` function declarations I declare a local variable using `var`, will it be available in another `document.ready` function declaration that's also used by the page?

No, they're local variables to the function you're passing into `document.ready`.

> I'm not sure how jQuery works in circumstances like these; whether it weaves the various functions' scopes together somehow or if each of those functions runs in standalone fashion when the ready event is fired, each having no idea about the others' variables. (I'd guess the second.)

And you'd be right. :-) In fact, jQuery *can't* comingle the execution contexts of the functions, those are managed by the JavaScript engine.

You can make them all share a parent execution context, though, by putting them all in a container function:

```
(function() {
    // Shared by all functions within this block
    var foo = 42;

    // ...

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (foo === 42) {
            // ...
            --foo;
        }
    });

    // ...

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (foo > 0) {
            // ...
            --foo;
        }
    });

})();
```

I don't think I'd advocate having multiple `ready` handlers (or even one, really) unless you're writing a library. But that's a different topic.

Comment: @apsillers: I really mean context, as in [execution context](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3). People frequently call that "scope," but that's loose terminology.

Comment: Aha! I see. I'd been using "context" to refer exclusively to the `this` variable -- this spec snippet makes it very clear what you mean. `this` is the programmatically-accessible component that is part of the larger logical construct that is the "execution context".

Comment: @apsillers: Yes, that came into fashion about six years ago (and went out again -- partially -- about three years ago, I'd say), partially because of the influence of the Prototype library I think (which used that term for it), but it's never a term that's been used in the spec, I think because it's too easily confused. :-) I clarified the answer when I saw your question, thanks. We really could use a good term for the meaning of "this." The spec uses `thisArg` for the name of arguments to `bind` and such, which is just *so* awkward. ;-) *Accurate*, but awkward.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't. Each `$(document).ready` will define it's own scope. If you need something visible to both, you can either make it a global, or define all your `$(document).ready` within another closure (using a self-invoking function for example).